# Not able to view the response in HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, get

I am not able to view the JSON response from the server on my HTML page. Request is sent to server once the user clicks on the button. By making an API call from AJAX in javascript, I am trying to display the response.

Here is my html page:
[image]

This is the response which I get using POSTMAN:

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "success_Result": {
    "names": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "text1"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "text2"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "text3"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my javascript:

```
   $("#search").click(function()
    { 
       $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/********/1/1/1?start_date=2017-02-10",
            async:true,
            dataType : 'jsonp',
            crossDomain:true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            headers: 
            {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'x-requested-with'
            },
            success: function(result) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                    alert(result);
                    //$("#display").html(result);
                }
                catch (error) 
                {
                    alert("error found");
                }   
            },   
            error: function(xhr, status, err)
            {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        });     
    });
```

Firebug: **console**
I can view the response here by clicking on the arrow.
[image: firebug: console]

I tried using `datatype: "json"` in javascript. and I got this in the console. And nothing i could see in the HTML page.

```
   $("#search").click(function()
   { 
     $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/*******/1/1/1?start_date=2017-02-10",
            async:true,
            dataType : 'json',
            crossDomain:true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            success: function(result) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                    alert(result);
                    //$("#display").html(result);
                }
                catch (error) 
                {
                    alert("error found");
                }   
            },   
            error: function(xhr, status, err)
            {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        });     
    });
```

**console:**
[image]

I tried other possible ways too....

```
                // using XMLHttpRequest
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/*******/1/1/1?start_date=2017-02-10", true);
            xhr.onload = function () 
            {
                try 
                {
                    $("#display").html("hello");
                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                }
                catch (ex) 
                {
                    alert('Error parsing response.');
                }
            };
            try 
            {
                xhr.send();
            }
            catch (ex) 
            {
                alert(ex.message);
            }
```

**console:**
[image]
Cross-origin resource sharing, Same origin policy error.

I don't know where i am going wrong. If anyone could help me out, it will be great. Please.

**@@@@@@@@@@@UPDATE@@@@@@@@@@@**

I tried this code now as per suggestions,

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/*******/1/1/1?start_date=2017-02-10",
            dataType : 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(result) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
                }
                catch (error) 
                {
                    alert("error found");
                }   
            },   
            error: function(xhr, status, err)
            {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        });
```

I got this is my **console:**

[image]
Headers in above image has something to say about CORS ?? Is it enabled or disabled ?? How to check ??

Comment: `headers: 
            {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'x-requested-with'
            }` does nothing. These headers are _response_ headers, to be sent by the server in response to your request. When used in a request they have no effect. If the remote server does not accept CORS requests, there is nothing you can do about, unless it happens to be your server. If it's your server, you need to configure it properly for CORS. Accessing a different port, such as 8080 like you're doing, counts as CORS.

Comment: and please don't use `async:true` - it's horrible for usability because it locks up the entire browser. There's really no need for it - in fact some browsers will issue a warning now if you use it. There's also no need to set `crossDomain:true` - this will force a request to be treated as CORS even when it isn't necessary.

Comment: CORS request can be sent however results can;t be displayed. The CORS needs to be enabled on the server side method.

Comment: @ADyson I have updated my question. Please check the last part. I am running HTML page from my local directory.

Comment: ok, well in that case you need to send CORS headers in the response from your server. You're still missing some, including the Allow-Origin one. These links might be helpful: https://enable-cors.org/server.html / https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Thank you @ADyson